# Symmetrize Rig / Bones Issue

Tags: rigging, bones, mirror, error

I'm running into an issue with symmetrize where it is successfully mirroring bones, but across the wrong pivot. My expectation was that it would mirror the bones over the main axis rather than around the pivot of one specific bone. Any idea what might be happening and how I can fix it? Attached are a few screenshots. Thanks for your help in advance!

[image: Cursor is at origin]

[image: after symmetrize]

[image: naming]

Comment: Doesn't seem possible to symmetrize on the Z axis (see the Operator box), so you probably need to rotate your armature in Object mode, symmetrize, then rotate it back

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I phrased it in a confusing way.  All the screenshots are taken from the front view facing the x axis. I’d like the bones to mirror from the right to the left using the up and down axis (Z) as the pivot.

Comment: symmetrize use the armature origin, not a bone, so your origin may not be place at the position you want?

Comment: This fixed it! I backed out into object mode, made sure the armature pivot was at origin, then went into edit mode and symmetrize worked perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try select all you want to simetrize and with right button chose "names" > left-right, and what you don't want to simetrize and choose "names" > top-bottom. So select the left-right bones and simetrize will use the top-bottom bones as reference.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As Moonboots suggested, the armature's origin was off, so symmetrize was mirroring at the wrong spot.